# Swift KeyPath on optional value

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift5

If I have

```
class Info {
    var name: String?
}

class User {
    var info: Info?
}

class WrappedClass {
    var user: User = User()
}


let nameKeyPath = \WrappedClass.user.info?.name //Gets me KeyPath
let referencedNameKeyPath = \WrappedClass.user.info!.name //Gets me ReferenceWritableKeyPath
```

`nameKeyPath` gets me a `KeyPath` which I can't later on use to modify the name value, but if I force unwrap it I get a `ReferenceWritableKeyPath` which is what I'm after.

Unfortunately using `referencedNameKeyPath` with a nil value along the line expectedly crashes, due to unexpectedly finding nil.

My question is is there a way to convert the `KeyPath` to a `ReferenceWritableKeyPath` or somehow unwrap it along the way?

Comment: Consider to use non-optional types as much as possible. An optional in a class as an alibi not to write an initializer is a pretty bad habit 

Comment: Unfortunately that’s not possible in my case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use optional chaining on keypaths. Create two keypaths one for user and the other one for name in info.

```
let infoKeyPath = \WrappedClass.user.info

let nameKeyPath = \Info.name
```

Now, use optional chaining with keypath and it will yield **String?** as the result.

```
let name = wrappedInstance[keyPath: infoKeyPath]?[keyPath: nameKeyPath]
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try having the key path as a computed optional variable. Like that:

```
class WrappedClass {
  var user: User = User()

  var nameKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<WrappedClass, String?>? {
    guard let _ = user.info else { return nil }
    return \WrappedClass.user.info!.name
  }
}
```

You still end up with the force unwrap notation but it should not cause any issues since you specifically guard for it.

That way you can use the computed key path in a safe and convenient way:

```
let instance = WrappedClass()

if let nameKeyPath = instance.nameKeyPath {
  instance[keyPath: nameKeyPath] = "Nikola"
}
```